# How to import tensorflow in javascript? Import in file, served by local http-server

Tags: javascript, node.js, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I'm following this tutorial:
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tfjs-training-classfication/index.html#2

I have set up a local HTTP-server, and that work and the app is running.
However, when I try to execute step 3 (Load the data), I get the following error when loading the data:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "@tensorflow/tfjs". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
```

If i comment out the import statment:

```
import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs';
```

the page actually loads and shows the sidebar with 16 handwritten digits.

1. Does this mean that TensorFlow is not loaded?
2. Is TensorFlow loaded, and I do not need this import statement?
3. Or maybe most important, why does the import not work??

Comment: Did you install the package with `npm install @tensorflow/tfjs ` ?

Comment: Yes. However, i changed alot of things, and now i dont get the previous error.But i  now get this error: **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word**, Could this be because i use node version 8.11.2, and that does not support the "await" word in that version of node? More spesifically it complains about this line: ** await tf.browser.toPixels(imageTensor, canvas**.

Comment: If you use await, you need to be in an `async` function. It is supported since node 8. You can edit your question with your new code so that we can see better

Comment: I'm having the same error as you @otk, what did you do to resolve the error while loading data?

Comment: @Arbitel I currently abandoned the .js path. THen started on the same project in python. I also tried to use the @tensorflow/tfjs-node packet without any more sucess... So no solution yet for the .js setup.

Answer (score 2):

you don't need to import the tfjs libraries if they are loaded as modules

in the html file put:

```
<html>
<meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">

<head>
    ...
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@1.5.2"></script>
    <script type="module" src="YOUR_CODE.js"></script>
    ...
</head>
​

<body>
    ...
</body>
​

</html>
```

And in YOUR_CODE.js simply put:

```
async function testModel() {
    const model = await tf.loadGraphModel(...);
    ...
    model.execute(pic);
    ...
}


testModel();
```